# Razorpay Payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay in my php codeigniter application (Cart Based).

Here I Put a request of eg: 250INR to Razorpay through Javascript.

But When I try to capture that money, I want to split that amount as multiple transactions.

In this case I am getting an error of Authorized amount and capturing amount should be same.

How Can I do this??

Thanks

Comment: From where you pass the amount in javascript and the post value to razorpay both are must be same.
Can you share some part of your code here?

Comment: $api->payment->fetch($payment_id)->capture(array('amount'=>($tempInfo->amount*100)));

Comment: Can I make it by creating order ??

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to capture total transaction amount of a particular order,partial capturing is not supported. Pls read the docs

https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/v1paymentsidcapture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To support partial payments either use razorpay payment links and enable the partial payment option. But in that case the user decides the partial payment amount he will be paying.
If you want to control the amount in each partial payment. Then you have to make different orders in razorpay corresponding to each partial payment. And handle the total amount at your end.